# connecting to gazebo model database

Tags: simulator, ros

I'm using gazebo simulator on Ubuntu 14.04.4.
I'm having problem to connect to the model database.

while I run gazebo I get the following errors:

> Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No  tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:407] Unable to download model[model://sun]
>
> Error [SystemPaths.cc:367] File or path does not exist[""]
>
> Error [parser.cc:523] Unable to find uri[model://sun]
>
> Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
>
> Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
>
> Msg Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No  tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:407] Unable to download model[model://ground_plane]
>   Error [SystemPaths.cc:367] File or path does not exist[""]
>
> Error [parser.cc:523] Unable to find uri[model://ground_plane]
>   [ INFO] [1462749167.054486531, 0.024000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
>   [ INFO] [1462749167.150879357, 0.095000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No  tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
>
> Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests

I tried looking up for the errors but I got no helpful answer.

In the "Insert" tab I see "conneting to model database..."

Comment: You will be able to expect the best response about Gazebo at their dedicated forum http://answers.gazebosim.org

Answer (score 3):

You can download all the models here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models, then save all the model files in ~/.gazebo/models.
Then two problem about manifest and database.config are left. In fact i don't know how to solve it, but it seems that it just doesn't matter.